# 400 Bad Request Error in Mozzila Firefox

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am trying to add a student in my database using Hibernate. I got a 400 Bad Request Error in Mozzila Firefox.

---------DAOImpl - here is DAO's method that insert a user in the DB---------

```
public void save(Student student) {
        LOG.debug(
                "inside save method from StudentDAOImpl with parameter student: {}",
                student);

        Session session = this.sessionFactory.openSession();

        session.save(student);
    }

  ------  ServiceImpl -here is service's method --------


     public void add(Student student) {

                LOG.debug(
                        "inside add method from StudentServiceImpl with parameter student: {}",
                        student);

                studentDAO.save(student);
            }

  ------  StudentController - this is controller's method for add a student -------


     @RequestMapping(value = RequestURL.ADD_STUDENT, method = RequestMethod.POST)
            @ResponseBody
            public void addStudent(@RequestBody AddStudentRequest addStudentRequest) {

                User user = new User(addStudentRequest.getUsername(),
                        addStudentRequest.getPassword(), Role.ROLE_STUDENT);
                userService.add(user);

                System.out.println("am salvat user-ul");
                user = userService.findByUsername(addStudentRequest.getUsername());
                int userId = user.getId();
                try {
                    int groupId = studentGroupService
                            .getIdByGroupNumber(addStudentRequest.getGroup());
                    int specializationId = specializationService
                            .getIdByName(addStudentRequest.getSpecialization());
                    Student student = new Student(userId, specializationId,
                            addStudentRequest.getName(),
                            addStudentRequest.getRegistrationNumber(), groupId,
                            addStudentRequest.getYear());
                    studentService.add(student);
                } catch (StudentGroupNumberNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (SpecializationNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

  -------  student.jsp - jsp page for student ------

function addStudent() {

        var username = $('#modalStudentUsername').val;
        var password = $('#modalStudentPassword').val();
        var name = $('#modalStudentName').val;
        var registrationNumber = $('#modalStudentRegistrationNumber').val;
        var group = $('#modalStudentGroup').val;
        var year = $('#modalStudentYear').val;
        var specialization = $('#modalStudentSpecializationId').val;

        var data = '{ "username" : "' + username + '", "password": "'
        + password + '", "name":"' + name
        + '","registrationNumber": "' + registrationNumber + '" , "specialization": "' + specialization 
        + '","group": "' + group+'", "year": " ' + year + '" }';

        var token = $('#csrfToken').val();
        var header = $('#csrfHeader').val();

        $.ajax({
                    type : "POST",
                    url : "student/add",
                    contentType : 'application/json',
                    data : data,

                    beforeSend : function(xhr) {
                        xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
                        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
                        xhr.setRequestHeader(header, token);
                    }, 

                    success : function(data, status, xhr) {
                        alert("Studentul a fost adaugat cu succes!");
                    },
                    error : function(xhr, status, errorThrown) {
                        alert("Student nu a fost salvat, deoarece a intervenit o eroare!");
                    },
                });
    }

<body>
    <input type="hidden" id="csrfToken" value="${_csrf.token}" />
    <input type="hidden" id="csrfHeader" value="${_csrf.headerName}" />
</body>

    If there are anyone who can help me, i will be very grateful! Thanks!
```

Comment: Did you see the request parameters going in your AJAX request in Dev Tools ? F12 - Network tab. See if all the parameters you're expecting are going properly. 400 bad request means that request parameters format is not valid, either they're truncated or your code is not sending valid values

Comment: Code like this `var name = $('#modalStudentName').val;` will not work. It should be `val()` as in function not just `val` as in a property :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have any transaction management configured? The service add method (or the DAO save method) should either have a transaction configured, or you start a transaction from Hibernate Session.beginTransaction() and then manually commit it.

the error might be raised because you have an unhandled exception raised in your code (can be a NullPointerException on accessing the return from findByUsername, because the save was not committed, I cannot tell unless I see the finder's code).

Also, it might be raised because on the server-side the de-serialization of the request body into AddStudentRequest instance was not possible (maybe different parameter names, or expected types). You have to check to see if the names of the parameters you set-up in the request, are the same as the attribute names in AddStudentRequest class, and also the expected types are compatible with that you send in the request.

Comment: 400 bad request means that there's something wrong with the request he's sending, not some issue while processing it :)

Comment: @Arkantos, you are right, it is either with the request is sending, or the server might throw it when it tries to instantiate AddStudentRequest with the values it receives from the request. That is why I mentioned in the answer also this possibility. But, for the first part, with transaction management, most probably he should get 500 Internal Server Error or something.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `val()` method to get the value of a particular form field instead of just `val` because the second one will throw an error as there's no such property in jQuery wrapper object.

Change your code like below to use `val()`

```
    var username = $('#modalStudentUsername').val();
    var password = $('#modalStudentPassword').val();
    var name = $('#modalStudentName').val();
    var registrationNumber = $('#modalStudentRegistrationNumber').val();
    var group = $('#modalStudentGroup').val();
    var year = $('#modalStudentYear').val();
    var specialization = $('#modalStudentSpecializationId').val();
```

You can even combine the initialization of these variables like

```
    var username = $('#modalStudentUsername').val(),
        password = $('#modalStudentPassword').val(),
        name = $('#modalStudentName').val();
```

You don't have to concate all these vars as strings, you can simply create a javascript object to hold your variables, jQuery will take care of conversion while making the AJAX call.

```
    var data = { 
       "username" : username ,
       "password": password ,
       "name": name,
       "registrationNumber": registrationNumber,
       "specialization": specialization ,
       "group": group,
       "year": year
    };
```